# Azure blobstorage error when reading file

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I've a file containing which I upload to Azure blobstorage, the file looks like this:

```
TAR-2312;12;;123;1A1195061;231
SSS 2637218;2/9;              
1A1321268;1231195061
```

My trigger processes the file, but I get `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "path.../TAR-2312;12;;123;1A1195061;231 SSS 2637218;2/9;1A1321268;1231195061`

It happens in the highlighted call

```
public static XDocument Convert(Stream blob)
{

   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(blob);
   var contentOfFile = reader.ReadToEnd();

   ***List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(contentOfFile).Take(2).ToList();***
```

Any ideas why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8) method expects path to a file and you're passing file contents.

In your scenario, it would be better to split the contents of the file using new line character delimiter (either `\n` or `\r\n`) using [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) method.

Comment: So you would just use something like List<string> lines = contentOfFile.split("\n").ToList();?

Comment: Yes, something like it.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

> ***List lines = File.ReadLines(contentOfFile).Take(2).ToList();***

File.ReadLines(string path) requires path and not the content. More details here: [ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_)

Whatever you are trying to achieve can be done as below:

```
//Get the reference of container and pass the blob name
CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference("BlobFileName.txt");
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
int countTake = 2;
using (var stream = blob.OpenRead())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        int count=0;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream && count!=countTake)
        {
            count++;
            lines.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, what if I want to exclude the line in the middle then?

Comment: You have to write some logic to remove. May be for example, you want only to read the lines at even row - then you need to keep skipping by 1 and so on.